# A phrase from the Wannsee Protocol

Tags: grammaticality

In the "Wannsee Protocol", we read the following phrase : "In großen Arbeitskolonnen, unter Trennung der Geschlechter, werden die arbeitsfähigen Juden straßenbauend in diese Gebiete geführt."

What is the grammatical function of "straßenbauend" ? Do you know another example of such a construction : "Sie werden [present participle] geführt", or better : "Sie werden [complement of a present participle] [present participle] geführt". Example that I invent : "Er wurde die Augen rollend zur Polizeiwache geführt." ("Geführt" can be replaced by another past participle.) Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

> In großen Arbeitskolonnen, unter Trennung der Geschlechter, werden die arbeitsfähigen Juden **straßenbauend** in diese Gebiete geführt.
>
> Er wurde die Augen **rollend** zur Polizeiwache geführt.
>
> Die Straße wird die Bahn nur einmalig **kreuzend** geführt.

That's all the adverbial use of the present participle. The action of the present participle happens at the same time as that of the predicate *geführt werden*.

Comment: Thanks. Couldn't "strassenbauend" be a "depiktives Prädikativ" ? I would like, if it was possible, an already existing example of the construction "Er wurde die Augen rollend zur Polizeiwache geführt." But thanks in any case.

Comment: The present participle has only two fundamentally different forms: in place of an adverb (no ending) or in place of an adjective (ending). One could split the adverb case into a *predicative* and an *adverbial* case, and rename the adjective case into *attributive*, but this seems to be fine-tuning to me. Please see my answer https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/41575/how-to-use-erg%c3%a4nzend-and-zus%c3%a4tzlich-in-sentences/41577#41577 to tell apart these **three** cases.

Comment: Fehlen da nicht Kommas? Z.B.: "Die Straße wird, die Bahn nur einmalig kreuzend, geführt."

Comment: Was für eine Art Nebensatz soll das denn sein?

Answer (score 2):

Literally this sentence says:

> The jews were lead to those areas **while **** were building roads.**

(I'll explain later, why I didn't say who was building roads.)

---

The present participle is used to describe an action that is happening while something else is going on, i.e. at the very same moment.

> Ilse tanzte **weinend.**
> Ilse was dancing **while she was crying.**

Sometimes you can merge a noun and a present participle to tell what is the thing that is involved in this parallel action:

> Heinz saß **brotkauend** am Boden.
> Heinz was sitting on the floor **while he was chewing bread**.

And of course you can use this construction also in passive voice:

> Martin wurde von Nadja **schimpfend** aus dem Haus gejagt.
> Martin was chased out of the house by Nadja **while she was scolding.**

But, if you omit the actor in a passive voice construction it often becomes unclear, if the subject or the unmentioned actor is the person that is performing the parallel action:

> Martin wurde **schimpfend** aus dem Haus gejagt.
> Martin was chased out of the house while **the chasing person** was scolding.
>
> Martin wurde weinend aus dem Haus gejagt.
> Martin was chased out of the house while **he** was crying.

So you can see, that the very same construction can be used to tell that
a) the unmentioned actor or
b) the subject
is performing the parallel action.

And this is why I wrote some stars. Both translations are possible:

> a) The jews were lead to those areas while **their leaders** were building roads.
> b) The jews were lead to those areas while **they** were building roads.

Comment: You're not wrong, but the sentence uses "werden geführt", present tense. That's "are being led / will be led", not "were led".

Answer (score 0):

Die Formulierung ist sprachlich nicht sehr gelungen.

> "In großen Arbeitskolonnen, unter Trennung der Geschlechter, werden
>   die arbeitsfähigen Juden straßenbauend in diese Gebiete geführt."

Entfernen wir die zur Analyse überflüssigen Teile:

> "In Arbeitskolonnen werden die Juden straßenbauend in diese Gebiete geführt."

Gemeint ist wohl, dass sie zum Straßenbau in diesen Gebieten in die Gebiete geführt werden, aber nur wenn die Führung in die Gebiete straßenbauend geschieht kann man obige Formulierung benutzen.

Nach meinem Eindruck kann sich das *straßenbauend* nur auf die Führenden beziehen, wie hier in einem äquivalent strukturierten Satz:

> In Kleingruppen werden die Kinder lachend von Pädagogen beaufsichtigt.

In diesem Satz bezieht sich das *lachend* m.E. klar auf die Pädagogen, nicht auf die Kinder. Das müsste lauten:

> In Kleingruppen werden die lachenden Kinder von (traurigen) Pädagogen beaufsichtigt.

Rückübertragen auf obiges Zitat:

> "In Arbeitskolonnen werden die straßenbauenden Juden in diese Gebiete geführt."

Es könnte natürlich sein, dass die Straßen selbst, die in die Gebiete führen, während der Führung, die in Wahrheit wohl eine Verschleppung ist, erst gebaut werden. Das Straßenbauen schreiben sich die Führer offenbar als eigene Leistung zu - das ist für die Leitung des Straßenbaus, auch wo er nicht auf Zwangsarbeit beruht, nicht unüblich.

Die Geschwindigkeit, mit der man beim Straßenbau vorwärts kommt, verträgt sich aber nicht gut mit dem Bild, in ein Gebiet geführt zu werden.

Comment: Zwangsarbeit Straßenbau schon auf dem Weg in die Gebiete. Von welcher Qualität sind denn die Straßen? Trampelpfade? Oder gleich ganz übertragener Sinn? Wege/Straßen formend? "Auf die Führenden" sollte es sich nicht beziehen können.

Comment: @LangLangC: Von Deinem ersten Satz ist ein Teil verloren gegangen. Beim zweiten ist der Tempus falsch: "Von welcher Qualität waren denn di Straßen?", oder? Welche Rolle spielt das? Ein übertragener Sinn erschließt sich mir nicht, kannst Du mir da auf die Sprünge helfen? Ich habe einige Dokumente aus der Zeit gelesen (Männerphantasien). "Straßenbauen" ist in der Sprache der Nazis so positiv besetzt, dass es sehr wahrscheinlich ist, dass sie sich selbst damit gemeint haben, führend eben, und straßenbauend. Wieso sollte es sich nicht auf sie beziehen können?

Comment: Die Ellipse meint, dass schon unterwegs Arbeit erpresst wird. "Die Führung" ist dabei personell in Unterzahl und nutzt keine Schaufeln. Nun kann diese Verschleierung ja Absicht sein, aber die Arbeit wird von den verschleppten erledigt,von der Führung bloß befohlen, unter großem Zwang und schnell, was bei minderwertigem Wegebau auch möglich ist. Übertragen wie Ameisenstraße, Menschenstraße, Trampelpfad. Grad bei Nazis ist oft zu lesen, was sie meinen gesagt zu haben und was sie da tatsächlich ausgesagt haben.  Wäre die Führung straßenbauend, dann ist das eine vollkommen abseitige Aktion,

Comment: ohne kausale Verbindung, nur temporal und geografisch verknüpft.

Comment: Dämme bauen, Landgewinnung, Straßenbau, Trockenlegung der Sümpfe - das stand hoch im Kurs bei den Nazis. Dass die Führung nicht selbst Hand an die Schaufel legte bedarf keiner besonderen Erwähnung. Beckenbauer holt die WM nach Deutschland, Dobrindt führt die Maut ein, Schröder reformiert die Sozialsysteme. Diese Zuschreibung der Leistung der Führungsebene ist heute so prevalent wie damals. Man muss m.E. fragen: "Wie werden sie geführt? Straßenbauend.", sprich, die Führung ist eine straßenbauende.

Comment: @LangLangC: Vielleicht hat sich das *nicht*, welches ich im ersten Satz beim Umformulieren verloren habe (erst stand da ein schärferes *halte ich für misslungen*) negativ auf die Verständlichkeit meiner Antwort als Ganzes ausgewirkt. Für gelungen halte ich die Formulierung keineswegs. Aber nach längerem Abwägen kann ich mir vorstellen, dass sie sowohl wie von mir analysiert, gedacht war, als auch verstanden wurde.

Comment: Danke für das "nicht". Inhaltlich: "Womit/wie werden sie getrieben?" Mit Straßenbau. Der Agent (Pädagogenbeispiel) fehlt. (Btw ist "Zuschreibung der Leistung" an die  Führungsebene meistens eine furchtbare Marotte. / Nebenbei  widerstrebt es mir langsam, im Zusammenhang mit diesen Ereignissen das Beispiel "Juden werden *geführt*" weiter zu benutzen.) ZZ wirkt das auf mich, als ob wir die Grammatik aus nazistischer Sicht oder aus historischer Perspektive analysieren. Das soll kein persönlicher Vorwurf sein. Eher ein Vorschlag, diese Unterschiede abwägend in die Antwort aufzunehmen.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74012/discussion-between-user-unknown-and-langlangc).